# Comandos Linux através do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, linux, artisan

Estou criando alguns comandos personalizados no Laravel conforme a documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan

ex:

```
php artisan gestao:config
```

Esse comando permite que eu já configure automaticamente algumas coisas em minha aplicação, como `migrate` e `Seeds` da minha aplicação.

O que gostaria de saber é se é possível executar além dos comandos do Artisan, alguns comandos nativos linux, como por exemplo: `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/storage`

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer usando o componente "process" (laravel 5) http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Também pode invocar as funções próprias do PHP 
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php, 
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php

Ou, ainda no Laravel (4.2), o componente [SSH](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ssh)

Obviamente, qualquer um dos meios que escolher necessita de níveis de permissão de execução. Isso depende das permissões no Sistema Operacional.

Comento isso devido ao `sudo` no comando que apresentou na pergunta.

Qual opção escolher? Depende do que pretende fazer. Não há uma regra onde obrigue-o a usar o Artisan ou condene-o por usar as funções próprias do PHP.